# XamlParseException while creatng VSIX of DLL with embedded XAML files & image

Tags: exception, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, vsix

I want to create VSIX package of an SDK. SDK has two XAML page, one image & DLL. The VSIX project architecture is given below.

[image]

When I try to use that I am getting XamlParseException. Can you solve this problem ? Please don't give me any links. I already read Tim Heuer's article as well as MSDN doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xaml files need to be in redist